# How can I crack a werkzeug generate_password_hash() hash with hascat?

Tags: python, sha256, werkzeug, cracking, hashcat

I created a SHA256 hash of the password `123456` with this.

```py
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
print(generate_password_hash('123456', "sha256"))
```

And the output is:

```
sha256$xq5IdqcV$226e9165e4d2c014939ac591b27418d0e9a668b774a64a3e89b41caab0bee724
```

I tried searching for the mode to use to crack within hashcat. But I wasn't able to find it. Every mode I tried, gave me a **token length exception** or **Separator unmatched**. I thought maybe the format of the hash that should be specified is different.

My final goal is to find the correct mode to crack this hash with hashcat; or any other tool to crack these types of hashes(hashes generated with werkzeug generate_password_hash() function)

Comment: What have you researched about the SHA256 algorithm so far? What code have you written? What do you know about salting?

Comment: What are you going to do with the millions of dollars you're going to make when you crack SHA256?  Will you share?

Comment: What exactly did you pass as input? The stuff after the last dollar sign is the actual hash.

Answer (score 0):

First off:
SHA256 cannot be "cracked" as in "hacked", by a shortcut or anything, but you can bruteforce SHA256 Hashes.

That means you just try out as many passwords as possible, and look if it matches with the target hash.

To your question: You can crack SHA256 with hashcat in numerous ways, most of the time you want to use a wordlist, a list of passwords it should search through. You can download a lot of them online.

You have to craft your command by following the [docs](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=hashcat).

```
hashcat -m 1710 -a 0 {yourHash} {yourList}
```

`-m` stands for Mode, 1710 is SHA256

`-a` Is the attack mode, you can see the different attack modes in the docs above, 0 is Straight

YourHash and Your(Password)List should be self explanatory.

Comment: I did try this method with the hash I mentioned in the question, but it gives me a  Separator unmatched error. The command I used was, hashcat.exe -m 1710 -a 0 hash.txt rockyou.txt

Comment: @KavishkaGihan you may have sha2-256, this algorithm require hashcat -m 1400